# How to write document to specific node in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have SOLR nodes(let's say Master1-Slave1-Slave2). I know that I must write to Master, then Master will send document to appropriate node by signature. How can I tell Master to write document to specific node(i.e Slave2). Or is there specific API for doing that?

Comment: Are you using SolrCloud or are you doing regular replication?

Comment: Actually I don;t know the difference between SolrCloud and Regular replication, but as I know I did "SolrCloud"

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you are using SolrCloud or having your own master-slave manual setup. If your setup is using SolrCloud then, then you can use [Document Routing](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/06/13/solr-cloud-document-routing/) to do this. If your setup is using your own manual master-slave setup then it depends how you configured your setup.

Follow [SolrCloud documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud) to understand SolrCloud in detail.